# Watery Russet Baked Potato

Tags: baking, potatoes

I have tried cooking baked potatoes (Russets) using the Alton Brown recipe here:

http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/the-baked-potato-recipe.html

For some reason they keep coming out very watery. I seem to get the same results even after cooking the potatoes for >3 hours at over 400F.

I am definitely poking >20 holes with a fork, as deep as I can.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have an oven thermometer?  I cannot imagine how this recipe could fail if you have followed it, and the oven is working properly.

Comment: Don't have one, but will order one and try again.

Comment: No need to poke holes, it's an "old wives tale"

Comment: Watery potatoes are just a sign of the potatoes growing in a wet area. Try a different supplier

Comment: I would microwave two potatoes for 4 minutes, then cut them in half and, spray olive aerosol on them and then bake them in a George Foreman on low for 15 minutes. And leave it stand for another 5 mins. Saves lots of electricity and nice grilled potatoes. But actually since I have a 12 inch George Foreman, I could actually microwave 6 potatoes and then George foreman the halves or quarters on low for 30 minutes. Skin intact.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate all the advice! These would be for gnocchi FYI.

Comment: Cooking for 3 hours and they are still watery? That's got to be something wrong with the potatoes. You are putting them on the wire racks, you aren't placing them in liquid or something like that?

Comment: Are they actually watery in a way you'd notice when eating as a baked potato, or do they just have too much water to make gnocchi?

Comment: Yes, I was putting them directly on the wire racks....I used an oven thermometer this time (sorry for the delay in the update had to wait for Amazon to get it to me) and I got the same result...a sort of damp looking inside to the potato...very unappetizing...no way was it even edible as a baked potato. I even checked the internal temp and it was 210F which seemed fine. I figure the potatoes must be the reason at this point...going to try to switch to a different supplier. Thank you everyone for the wonderful help! I wish there was some way to give credit to everyone in the comments section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your oven is working correctly, it sounds like the potatoes are the culprit.  Try finding another store/source for your potatoes.  Also consider how you are storing your potatoes. Are they in a particularly humid environment?

Comment: Just storing the potatoes in my usual spot in the kitchen cupboard...so it is probably the potatoes themselves. Thank you so much for your help!